# Worksheet is sorted by an Apps Script function only if it is run manually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a simple script to sort my Google Sheet

```
function sort() {
  //Variable for column to sort first
  var sortFirst = 7; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A, 2 = column B, etc.
  var sortFirstAsc = false; //Set to false to sort descending 
  var headerRows = 1; 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}]);
}
```

The issue I am running into is it works perfect when I manually run it, but when I run it through a time-based trigger, it does nothing. Checking the logs, it shows it executed ran perfectly, but the outcome on the sheet does not reflect that it executed.

Manually Run:

```
[18-05-08 16:26:28:854 PDT] Starting execution
[18-05-08 16:26:28:990 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0.131 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:28:990 PDT] Sheet.getSheetName() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:28:991 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:28:992 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Call]) [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:28:992 PDT] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:29:087 PDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.094 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:29:088 PDT] Sheet.getRange([2, 1, 999, 12]) [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:29:090 PDT] Range.sort([[{column=7.0, ascending=false}]]) [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:26:29:214 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.232 seconds total runtime]
```

Run off time-based trigger:

```
[18-05-08 16:27:28:466 PDT] Starting execution
[18-05-08 16:27:28:775 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0.299 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:775 PDT] Sheet.getSheetName() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:777 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:777 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Call]) [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:778 PDT] Sheet.getMaxRows() [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:900 PDT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.121 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:901 PDT] Sheet.getRange([2, 1, 999, 12]) [0 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:28:902 PDT] Range.sort([[{column=7.0, ascending=false}]]) [0.001 seconds]
[18-05-08 16:27:29:038 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.429 seconds total runtime]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` will return the first sheet if the UI is not open. Have you checked if the very first sheet in your workbook is getting sorted? (You can verify which sheet is getting sorted by using `Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());`.)  Also, note that you double-reference the sheet. In your code, `activeSheet` and `sheet` are both references to the same object.

Comment: OMG I did not even think about the fact it did not know what sheet was active while not using the UI. I have made the corrections here but I am now getting an error on the following line.

`var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());`

Comment: Error I am getting is **Cannot call method "getRange" of null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, when the script is run by the time trigger, it is required to give the sheet name. So how about this modification?

#### Modified script :

```
function sort() {
  //Variable for column to sort first
  var sortFirst = 7; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A, 2 = column B, etc.
  var sortFirstAsc = false; //Set to false to sort descending 
  var headerRows = 1;

  var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Modified
  var sheetName = "### sheet name ###"; // Added
  var sheet = workbook.getSheetByName(sheetName); // Added

  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort([{column: sortFirst, ascending: sortFirstAsc}]);
}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this, please input the sheet name, and try to run by the trigger.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` are valid for bound Apps Script projects, even if a time-based trigger is running. However, you are correct that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` will return the 1st sheet when the workbook is not opened in the Google Sheets UI, which is not necessary the sheet OP is wanting to sort

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for the advice. I had used file ID when the script is run by a time trigger. So I could obtain new information from your comment. Thank you. And I modified my answer.

Comment: Yep, just because one uses a time-based trigger does not mean they need to use `openById`. Otherwise, it would be impossible to use the scope-limitation `// @OnlyCurrentDoc` with a bound document that needs time-based triggers :)

Comment: @tehhowch Yes. Thank you for additional information. I would like to use those information in my future script.

Comment: @jason helgerson I'm glad your issue was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.